# Transforming values from array of an object to vector in C++

Tags: c++

Each User has a field called id. And I want to create a vector containing all ids of the users returned by the API call.

> ```
> vector<int> ids;
> Users* users = // API CALL HERE
> for (auto i = 0; i < total_users; i++)
> {
>     logins.push_back(users[i].id);
> }
> ```

Is there a way to do this in a more clean way in C++?

Comment: Please edit the question to provide more context to the code that you want reviewed. It would also help if you could specify details such as what version of c++ you are using.

Answer (score 3):

You can almost always use a standard algorithm. It doesn't always look nicer though, but your intent is easier to read and you can benefit from the library's optimizations (and from parallelized algorithms with some luck)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

...
std::vector<int> ids;
std::transform(users, std::next(users, total_users), std::back_inserter(ids), 
               [](const auto& user) {
    return user.id;
});
```

Then it depends on the API call.

If the return value is a non-owning pointer, the best thing is to build a `span` from it. It isn't standardized, but is part of the [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines). It basically is a pointer bundled with a size. You could the use a `range based for loop`:

```
gsl::span<User> users( ... API CALL ... , total_users);
for (const auto& user : users) ...
```

If the pointer owns the memory it points to, it can be a bit trickier, because the resource must be freed the same way it was allocated: `malloc` -> `free`, `new` -> `delete`, `new[]` -> `delete[]`, etc. The best thing could be to use a smart pointer, but you'd need to specify the destructor to call. There is a level of complexity beyond which it is advisable to build a RAII wrapper around the legacy API, even if it looks like more work / complexity.

Answer (score 1):

The code looks generally fine (though a little too sketchy for a good review).  It does look like you have `using namespace std;` somewhere, which I advise against.

If you know how many elements you'll be adding to your vector, it's always a good idea to reserve sufficient capacity.  This reduces the amount of reallocation it might do if it can only react to the additions, and may help avoid over-allocation:

```
std::vector<int> ids;
ids.reserve(total_users);
// now, push_back() or transform()
```